# Angular *ngFor with jQuery Binding

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm trying to modify a horizontal timeline like https://codepen.io/ritz078/pen/LGRWjE/
The Demo comes with some hardcoded dates and I'm trying to replace them with an array of Dates (timelineParsedDates)

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="16/01/2014" class="selected">16 Jan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/2014">28 Feb</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="20/04/2014">20 Apr</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="20/05/2014">20 May</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="09/07/2014">09 Jul</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="30/08/2014">30 Aug</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="15/09/2014">15 Sep</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="01/11/2014">01 Nov</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="10/12/2014">10 Dec</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="19/01/2015">19 Jan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0" data-date="03/03/2015">3 Mar</a></li>
    <li *ngFor="let parsedDate of timelineParsedDates; let index = index;">
        <a  href="#0" data-date="parsedDate">{{parsedDate}}</a>
    </li>
<ol>
```

Capture from the browserconsole shows first the last hardcoded date (03/03/2015) and second a generated listitem with a-tag. The value for {{parsedDate}} is correctly & correctly displayed, but that data-data=" " reads this angular like a string and messes with the rest of the logic
[image]

If I try something like

```
data-date={{parsedDate}}
```

I Get following error:

Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'date' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. (""let parsedDate of timelineParsedDates; let index = index;">
<a  href="#0" [ERROR ->]data-date={{parsedDate}}>{{parsedDate}}

Anybody has an idea how I could maybe load those values dynamically into that data-data property?
I read mixing Angular with jQuery is not ideally, but it was the nicest horizontal timeline I could find. Also I'm fairly new to jQuery)
Cant really find any related questions on S/O so hoping to get some advice here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you absolutely have to use jQuery, then do it after you render the page. Simply make sure your component implements `AfterViewInit`. Then add any jQuery code inside `ngAfterViewInit() {...}`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Great Tip, thankyou! Was doing it in OnInit() untill now, but was going to run into problems later. Thanks for helping me before it happened))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Angular attribute binding like:

```
[attr.data-date]="parsedDate"
```